# Horizontal Label on DateTimeAxis dissappears sometimes after changing data, why?

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I'm working with an Adobe Flex project and I have data I'm plotting against a DateTimeAxis (X-axis) but because there are a lot of points, I have to do some manipulation and remove some objects in the array (I do this by copying data to another array, removing items, then copying the new array into the original array).  However, sometimes after I do this, the date labels disappear off of the x-axis!  Why does this happen?  I look through my array and I cannot find a reason its occurring (no objects with nothing in them, everything appears in chronological order).   Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It appears the DateTimeAxis is a buggy component. Try to set the disabledDays property to [].

Also, the DateTimeAxis is sometimes not able to compute proper values for its labels, so it simply displays nothing. I guess...

BTW, have you tied to use the slice method to give a piece of your original data to your chart, instead of performing add and remove manipulations ? It could be faster...